# Decomposing a fraction having square rooted terms in denominator

Tags: calculus

I need to decompose the fraction into partial fractions. My aim is to take integral of it.

$$\frac{a-b}{(x-a)\sqrt{x-b}\sqrt{x-c}}$$
where a, b, c are constants.

Thanks..

Comment: [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F((x-a)sqrt(x-b)sqrt(x-c)) might help.

Comment: and, if you want the integration, [using wolfram alpha is *always* a good idea](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%281%2F%28%28x-a%29sqrt%28x-b%29sqrt%28x-c%29%29%29)

Comment: thank you @Sabyasachi, i will try your first suggestion.

Comment: okay. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 6):

Partial fraction decomposition applies only to *rational functions*: functions in which both the numerator and denominator are *polynomials*.

In your problem, the denominator is NOT a polynomial, hence you cannot use partial fraction decomposition in this case.

Comment: I upvoted you, but *very* interestingly, you might wanna [see this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F((x-a)sqrt(x-b)sqrt(x-c)))

Comment: It's just a matter of definition. Usually the term *partial decomposition* is for rational functions. It is the case that it can be generalized, but by definition, it is not a partial decomposition.

Comment: @GitGud don't you think that the OP was asking for a decomposition? *Must* we fuss about the word *partial*?

Comment: @Sabyasachi I don't know if we must. I choose to do so. It's easier to take things literally.

Comment: @GitGud you're a little evil. Anyway I am feeling lazy, so  I will just leave the OP a link to wolfram alpha. why work here?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thank you, thank you $\ddot \smile$